# Android Things SD card corrupt after working for a few days

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using Android Things with my Raspberry Ii 3 Model B. I wrote the image file through Etcher onto the SD card.

My app starts working for some days and after some days, SD card occurs corrupting and some error comes on my screen.

For reference, I have attached an image which comes on my screen.

[image]

Comment: The SD card will likely become corrupted/destroyed when the power drops out while the card is being written. A class 10 card maybe less prone to that and make sure to have the software turning off the Raspberry PI. Make also sure you neither use a counterfeit SD card.

Comment: This would seem more at home on [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) or [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com). However, please do not cross-post.

Comment: Raspberry Pis are notorious for corrupting SD cards. Boosting the SD card voltage usually helps.

Comment: Or the SD card itself is low quality. In general, an SD card for a use like this might not be the best thing.

Comment: JakeGould, Then What should I use? As we are working on Android Things with Raspberry Pi so we need SD card.